# how to convert 'int' to 'objectParameter'?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I saw vice versa is possible by using the ".value" from objectParameter

```
int repid = Int32.Parse(reportId);
```

Passing rapidly ahead to SP as the parameter which gives an error

> Cannot convert 'int' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'

```
public virtual int usp_AuditLogger(  ObjectParameter reportId)
{
   //this is where I need that value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectParameter` is not a datatype to change from one type to other but you can assign Value to `Value` Property of that class by creating a new instance of `ObjectParameter` class.

```
 int anyValue=12;
 ObjectParameter reportId=new ObjectParameter("reportId", anyValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectParameter is a class with two properties, the name and the value. So in your method, if you really wanna passe ObjectParameter in parameters you must create this object with a name `reportId` in your example and the value of `reportId`.

```
 public virtual int usp_AuditLogger(ObjectParameter report )
    {
    int _reportId = report.value;
       //this is where i need that value
    }
```

Or you could change the input parameter in your function to expect an int:

```
public virtual int usp_AuditLogger(int reportId)
{
   //this is where i need that value
}
```